# Difference between virtualenv and virtualenv-3.4

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, homebrew

I've installed Python 3.5 using Homebrew

`brew install python3`

Then I installed `virtualenv` using `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`

But I see 2 similar files in my `/usr/local/bin`, namely `virtualenv` and `virtualenv-3.4`. Both give the same virtualenv version (13.1.2) when I check using `virtualenv --version` or `virtualenv-3.4 --version`.

Please tell me the difference between the 2 files and which one to use in which case.

Comment: You may want to check first, if they are links, and to what file they are pointing. Probably `virtualenv` is just a symlink to `virtualenv-3.4` and then your question is already answered.

Comment: They are not links. The output of `ls -l` in `/usr/local/bin`:


`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root        admin       232 Sep 27 23:16 virtualenv`
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root        admin       232 Sep 27 23:16 virtualenv-3.4`

Comment: Next step is to print the shebang: `head -1 /usr/local/bin/virtualenv`. This should give you the python version that is called, when this particular file is executed.

Comment: Running your command both on `virtualenv` and `virtualenv-3.4` gives the same output: `#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5`

Comment: If they're running the same version of `virtualenv` on the same interpreter, why does it matter what (if anything) the difference is?

Comment: Was just wondering why there are 2 files for the same purpose then. Shouldn't there just be one file to avoid the confusion in the first place?

Comment: The plain `virtualenv` executable is for your convenience. If you have multiple versions, e.g. `virtualenv-3.5` and `virtualenv-3.4` a simple `vir<tab>` will (if you are not a virtualbox fan :)) suffice to complete to `virtualenv`. You don't have to explicitly type the version identifier.

Comment: That makes sense. Also, would you be able to tell me why `virtualenv-3.4` is named like that even though the version of virtualenv is 13.1.2. 

I'm fairly new to SO. So, please do tell me if this has to be posted as a separate question, or if the question is too noob-ish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed one version of `virtualenv` then both files `virtualenv` and `virtualenv-3.4` will be exactly the same. You can check this with a command like

```
cmp --silent /usr/local/bin/virtualenv /usr/local/bin/virtualenv-3.4 && echo 'Same'
```

which will output `'Same'` if the 2 files are identical.

The reason for the different names is so that you can (if you wish) use multiple versions of `virtualenv` interchangeably on your system. Whilst `virtualenv` itself can be used as a convenience and to refer to the latest version of `virtualenv`.